# Cannot install npm package in Github registry

Tags: github, npm, github-package-registry

I have published a package to the GitHub npm registry. I can see the package when I login onto GitHub, as per the screenshots below.

**ScreenShot 1**
[image]

**ScreenShot 2**
[image]

Locally, a different package has the former as a dependency. Therefore I have on my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "<@scope>/<package_name>": "1.2.0",
...
```

I also have, in-line with the documentation, a `.npmrc` file at the same directory as the `package.json` with the authToken. This authToken has all the permissions necessary (`delete:packages, read:packages, repo, write:packages`)

```
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=<my_auth_token>
registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/OWNER
```

Lastly, I have on `package.json` the following two entries. Although I believe these are necessary to publish packages to the github registry, no to install them which is the current problem.

```
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/<OWNER>/<REPO>.git"
  }
```

So, the error that I am having when I try to install the package is:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: <@scope>/<package_name>@1.2.0
```

When I tried to understand what was going on with some helpful logs:
With `npm install @<scope>/<package_name>@1.2.0 --loglevels verbose`, I see:

```
....
npm http fetch GET 200 https://npm.pkg.github.com/OWNER/@<scope>%2f<package_name>
npm http fetch GET 404 https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/@<scope>/<package_name>/1.2.0/98e69e2adddec5c715a32c94352efac83ce586e4e6f3d06fef1fc1f82d238r34
...
```

The first http request is a success, which seems to indicate things are correctly wired up and authenticated. However, I have no idea why I am getting a 404 afterwards. The package is clearly there as we see on the image above.

Does anyone had a similar problem ?

Comment: I am having the same problem. I have noticed that when I run `npm info @scope/name` it works fine, but it's the install step that fails. It happens both with yarn and npm client.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 7):

Well, my own .npmrc (in my home directory) is configured as this:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=<token>
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=<token>
@myorg1:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
@myorg2:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
```

I've not added my org in the github registry URL as you did, and specified the registry to use for each scope.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue. Removing package-lock.json fixed it for me. I suspect the problem was that I previously installed the offending package from a tarball and that the old installation information was somehow cached inside the package-lock.json

Answer (score 0):

I had misread the checkboxes in my PAT. Make sure you've enabled `read:packages`.

My successful .npmrc file looks like this:

```
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=TOKEN_GOES_HERE
```